# python inputを変数に入力する方法

Tags: python

keijoのアンダースコアの隣にyear2のインプットを。net_worthのアンダースコアの隣にyear1とyear2をいれたいのですがエラーがでて計算できません。
どうすれば、うまく計算できるでしょうか？

```
net_worth_1 = 308009
net_worth_2 = 233488
net_worth_3 = 315739
　　　　
keijo_pro_1 = 8000
keijo_pro_2 = 9000
keijo_pro_3 = 10000
　　　　
year1 = input("Enter first year:")
year2 = input("Enter end year:")
　　　　　
roa = keijo_year2 / ((net_worth_year1 +  net_worth_year2) / 2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

やりたいことは使用する変数を数値入力して選択することでしょうか。

`input`で取得した文字列をそのまま変数名に書き換えることはできませんので、`eval`や`exec`を使って動的に変数名を生成する必要があります。

```
net_worth_1 = 308009
net_worth_2 = 233488
net_worth_3 = 315739

keijo_pro_1 = 8000
keijo_pro_2 = 9000
keijo_pro_3 = 10000

year1 = input("Enter first year:") #例えば「1」を入力
year2 = input("Enter end year:")   #例えば「2」を入力

cmd = 'keijo_pro_{1} / ((net_worth_{0} +  net_worth_{1}) / 2)'.format(year1, year2)
# 上記の例の通り入力した場合、cmdは "keijo_pro_2 / ((net_worth_1 +  net_worth_2) / 2)" となる
roa = eval(cmd) #evalで動的に式を実行して計算後の値を取得する
print(roa) #0.033241181391586654
```

動的に式を変換して実行するよりも、リストを使う方が可読性が高く、後で機能変更することも容易になりますので、下記のように書き換えることをお勧めします。

```
net_worth = {} #1から始まるので辞書{}を使っていますが、0から始めるなら配列[]でも良いです
net_worth['1'] = 308009
net_worth['2'] = 233488
net_worth['3'] = 315739
keijo_pro = {'1':8000, '2':9000, '3':10000}

year1 = input("Enter first year:") #例えば「1」を入力
year2 = input("Enter end year:")   #例えば「2」を入力

roa = keijo_pro[year2] / ((net_worth[year1] +  net_worth[year2]) / 2)
print(roa) #0.033241181391586654
```

Comment: なるほど！そもそもインプットでやるよりリストのほうが扱いやすいですね！インプットで直感的に理解しやすいので、インプットを使いがちでしたが、ここではリストが適切ですね！ありがとうございます！参考になりました！